# Intercepting explicit interface implementations with Castle Dynamic Proxy

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

I am having trouble getting Castle Dynamic Proxy to intercept methods that are explicit interface implementations. I read here http://kozmic.pl/category/dynamicproxy/ that it should be possible to do this. 
Here are my classes;

```
internal interface IDomainInterface
{
    string DomainMethod();
}

public class DomainClass : IDomainInterface
{
    string IDomainInterface.DomainMethod()
    {
        return "not intercepted";
    }
}
```

Here is my interceptor class;

```
public class DomainClassInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name == "DomainMethod")
            invocation.ReturnValue = "intercepted";
        else
            invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

And here is my test (which fails);

```
    [TestClass]
    public void can_intercept_explicit_interface_implementation()
    {
        // Create proxy
        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var interceptor = new DomainClassInterceptor();
        var proxy = (IDomainInterface)generator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(DomainClass), interceptor);

        // Invoke proxy method
        var result = proxy.DomainMethod();

        // Check method was intercepted -- fails
        Assert.AreEqual("intercepted", result);
    }
```

In addition to not being able to intercept the explicit interface implementation, it also seems that I am not receiving a notification of a non-proxyable member.
Here is my proxy generation hook (which acts as a spy);

```
public class DomainClassProxyGenerationHook : IProxyGenerationHook
{
    public int NonProxyableCount;

    public void MethodsInspected() {}

    public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        NonProxyableCount++;
    }

    public bool ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my test (which again fails);

```
    [TestMethod] 
    public void receive_notification_of_nonproxyable_explicit_interface_implementation()
    {
        // Create proxy with generation hook
        var hook = new DomainClassProxyGenerationHook();
        var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions(hook);
        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var interceptor = new DomainClassInterceptor();
        var proxy = (IDomainInterface)generator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(DomainClass), options, interceptor);

        // Check that non-proxyable member notification was received -- fails
        Assert.IsTrue(hook.NonProxyableCount > 0);
    }
```

Has anyone had success in getting DP to intercept explicit interface implementations? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a class proxy. Class proxy only intercepts virtual methods on the class, and an explicit implementation of an interface method in C# by definition is not virtual (since it's private).

If you want to intercept methods on the interface you need to explicitly tell DynamicProxy about it

```
var proxy = (IDomainInterface)generator.CreateClassProxy(typeof(DomainClass), new Type[] { typeof(IDomainInterface) }, interceptor);
```

Also your interface is marked as `internal` so made sure it's `public` for DynamicProxy (either make the interface public or add `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`).

With that your first test will pass, and the method will be intercepted.

Comment: Yep, that is now doing exactly what I wanted. Thanks.